# How to show Martingale property for sum of $S_k-E(S_k)$-summands where $S_k$ is a function of two RV's

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, martingales

cEDIT: new formulation of the question (old version below).

In a paper I found the statement that a certain sum $M_n =Y_1+\dotsb Y_n$ is a martingale, $Y_i=f (X_k, Z_k) - E ( f(X_k, Z_k) | X_k)$. (The new $S_k$ would be $:=f(X_k, Z_k)$ but I won't use this in the new formulation of the question).
We have $E(f(X_k, Z_k) | X_k) = E(f(X_k, Z_k) | \mathcal{F}^X_k)$ with $\mathcal{F}^X_k=\{X_1, \dots, X_k\}$. $Z_k$ is iid, and ($X_k$, $Z_k$) are independent for each $k$, f is differentiable.

**How can I assert that this is a martingale?**

Let me explain what I know so far about the filtrations:
In the original question (see bottom) I thought I would have to use the natural filtration, which doesn't seem to fulfill the martingale property. Then @Gortaur suggested to use the filtration $\mathcal{F}^X_k$. I wondered why this is measurable with respect to the filtration ([question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69773/14126)) - it isn't. So to achieve $M_n$ being a martingale, we have to choose at least the filtration $D_k:=\mathcal{F}^{(X, Z)}_k$, but with this filtration the martingale property doesn't seem to hold (instead of $E(M_{k+1} | F_k)=M_k$, $E(Y_{k+1}|F_k)=0$ is sufficient):

$$E(Y_{k+1}|D_k)=E(f(X_k, Z_k) | D_k) - E(E( f(X_k, Z_k ) | \mathcal{F}^X_k ) | D_k) = f(X_k, Z_k) - E(f(X_k, Z_k)|\mathcal{F}^X_k) $$

And if the subtrahend would be $=f(X_k, Z_k)$ then it would have to be $\mathcal{F}^X_k$-measurable as a version of this conditional expectation which it would not be in general (consider Doob's Lemma for example in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69773/measurability-question-for-martingale-is-sx-i-z-i-esx-i-z-i-mid-mathca/69781#69781) to my other question)

---

Link to the paper:
[here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.19.4562) .
In the notation there, $X_k:=\hat{\theta_k}$, $Z_k:= \Delta_k$ and $f=\hat{g}_{ki} (\hat{\theta_k})=\frac{L(\hat{\theta_k} + c_k \Delta_k)-L(\hat{\theta_k} - c_k \Delta_k)}{2c_k \Delta_{ki}}$ (I assume that I can deal with the cancelation of  noise terms via the paper's assumption $ E(\epsilon_k^+ - \epsilon_k^- | F_k, \Delta_k) =0 $ and put the noise-less $L$ directly for $f$)

---

---

The original question:

I want to show that a sum is a martingale sequence, $M_n=Y_1+\dots+Y_n$.
I know that it is sufficient to show that $E(Y_{n+1} | M_n) =0$ a.s.
Unfortunately, the sum is rather complicated, $Y_k=S_k - E(S_k|X_k)$, where
$S_k=\frac{f(X_k, Z_k)}{Z_k}$.
That means for $k=1$:
$$ E[Y_2 | Y_1] = E \left[ \tfrac{f(X_2, Z_2)}{Z_2} - E \left(\tfrac{f(X_2, Z_2)}{Z_2} \right | X_2) | \tfrac{f(X_1, Z_1)}{Z_1} - E \left(\tfrac{f(X_1, Z_1)}{Z_1} \right | X_1) \right] =0 $$

I think I will have to use that $E(Y_k)=0$, and I could if I knew, that $Y_k$ independent from $Y_1+\dots +Y_{k-1}$. $Z_k$ is an independent sequence and $X_2$ is more or less $X_1+f(X_1,Z_1)$ but still, the intuition would be that how far $Y_1$ is away from it's expectation is independent from how far $Y_2$ is
**Q: How can I show that $M_n$ is a martingal sequence?** Are my preliminary considerations right? Would you think with this way one can show martingale property? Do I have to impose additional conditions on $f$ ?

I am thankful vor every hint

Note: $f:R^m \times R \to R$, $(X_k (\omega) , Z_k(\omega) ) \mapsto f(X_k (\omega) , Z_k(\omega) )  $

EDIT: I had forgotten, that in $Y_k$ we have the conditional expectation on $X_k$ instead of expectation per se.

Comment: @Gortaur: with $\stackrel{!}{=}0$ I wanted to say that the expression **should** be 0

Comment: Sorry, never seen this notation.

Comment: $X_{k+1}=X_k+f(X_k,Z_k)$ so $X_k$ is a Markov chain. The $Z_k$ are iid. $Z_k$ and $X_k$ are independent. Maybe there are general results when Markov chains are Martingale sequences?

Comment: There are, like $g(X)$ is a martingale iff $\mathcal P g(x) = g(x)$ for all $x$, where $\mathcal P g(x) = \mathsf E_x[f(X_1)]$. In your question $S$ is already not necessary Markov.

Comment: @Gortaur What do you mean with $E_x$ in $E_x [g(X)]$? (You wanted to define $Pg(x):= E_x [g(X)]$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement of this question has witnessed so many patches and modifications that I find difficult to spot the exact hypotheses. Hence I will formulate a question which might or might not be the one that interests you, and I will answer it. The idea is that if this is not the question you wanted to ask, at least you will be able to set things straight starting from this answer.

Here we go. You are given two independent sequences $(X_n)$ and $(Z_n)$, which you further assume to be independent from each other. You consider some sigma-algebras $F_n$, such that, for every $n$, $(X_{n+1},Z_{n+1})$ is independent on $F_n$, and, for some given (sufficiently integrable) functions $f_n$, the random variables $Y_n=f_n(X_n,Z_n)-\mathrm E(f_n(X_n,Z_n)\mid X_n)$.

Note that $F_n$ might be the sigma-algebra generated by the random variables $X_k$ and $Z_k$ for every $k\leqslant n$, or the sigma-algebra generated by the random variables $X_k$ for every $k\leqslant n$, or any other sigma-algebra which fits the bill that $(X_{n+1},Z_{n+1})$ is independent on $F_n$.

The question is whether $\mathrm E(Y_{n+1}\mid F_n)=0$, almost surely.

The answer is yes and the proof is direct. Since $Y_{n+1}$ is measurable with respect to $(X_{n+1},Z_{n+1})$ which is independent from $F_n$, one knows that $\mathrm E(Y_{n+1}\mid F_n)=\mathrm E(Y_{n+1})$, almost surely. By the [tower property](http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/313/Martingales.pdf), the expectations of the random variables $f_{n+1}(X_{n+1},Z_{n+1})$ and $\mathrm E(f_{n+1}(X_{n+1},Z_{n+1})\mid X_{n+1})$ are both $\mathrm E(f_{n+1}(X_{n+1},Z_{n+1}))$. Hence $\mathrm E(Y_{n+1}\mid F_n)=0$, almost surely.

Now, it is up to you: shoot...

---

**Edit** Allright, so you shot (see the comments)... As a result, the setting is still not entirely clear but seems to be closer to the following than to what I wrote above.

Consider independent random variables $X_0$ and $Z_n$ for $n\geqslant0$. Assume that $(Z_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ is i.i.d. For every $n\geqslant0$, define the random variables 
$$
X_{n+1}=h(X_n,Z_n),\quad
U_n=f(X_n,Z_n),\quad
Y_n=U_n-\mathrm E(U_n\mid X_n).
$$
Let us fix $n\geqslant0$, let $G_n$ denote any sigma-algebra such that $(X_n,Z_n)$ is $G_n$-measurable and $Z_{n+1}$ is independent on $G_n$, and let us prove that $\mathrm E(Y_{n+1}\mid G_n)=0$, almost surely.

Consider the function $g$ defined on the state space of every $X_n$ by 
$g(x)=\mathrm E(f(x,Z_1))$.

Then, on the one hand, $X_{n+1}=h(X_n,Z_n)$ is $G_n$-measurable, $Z_{n+1}$ is independent on $G_n$ and  $U_{n+1}=f(X_{n+1},Z_{n+1})$, hence $\mathrm E(U_{n+1}\mid G_n)=g(X_{n+1})$. Now, $\mathrm E(U_{n+1}\mid G_n)$ is $X_{n+1}$-measurable hence $\mathrm E(U_{n+1}\mid X_{n+1})=\mathrm E(\mathrm E(U_{n+1}\mid G_n)\mid X_{n+1})=g(X_{n+1})$ and $\mathrm E(Y_{n+1}\mid G_n)=0$.

This proves that $(M_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ is an $(F_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ martingale, where $M_0=0$ and $M_n=Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$ for every $n\geqslant1$, as soon as $(F_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ denotes a filtration (hence $F_n\subseteq F_{n+1}$ for every $n\geqslant0$) such that each $F_n$ satisfies the conditions we put on $G_n$ above. This means that for every $n\geqslant0$,  $F_n$ is independent on $\sigma(Z_{n+1})$ and $H_n\subseteq F_n$, where
$$
H_n=\sigma(X_0)\vee\sigma(Z_k;0\leqslant k\leqslant n).
$$
An example of such a filtration is $F_n=H_n$ for every $n\geqslant0$, but each $F_n$ may contain some extraneous information.

Comment: $X_n$ is not an independent sequence, only $Z_k$

Comment: I guessed so. Question: what are exactly and precisely the independence assumptions you want to make?

Comment: $Z_n$ iid sequence, $X_k$ and $Z_k$ independent for all k. (The dependence of $X_k$ on its predecessor is of the kind $X_{k+1} = X_k + h(X_k, Z_k, \omega)$, $h$ evaluates $f$ at $X_k \pm Z_k$ with some extra noise (therefore $\omega$), in the notation of the paper $\hat{\theta}_{k+1} $ $= \hat{\theta_k} - a_k \hat{g_k} (\hat{\theta_k}) $) And thank you a lot for your effort!

Comment: Is $Z_n$ independent on $\{X_k;k\leqslant n\}$?

Comment: I was more or less unaware of "conditional independence" - it is not stated explicitly in the paper and the related papers - so if it is, then I have to deduce it from the other conditions in the paper.. Intuitively I would think that yes, because $Z_n$ is a generated pseudo-random number and $X_k$ the current result of the process (which uses Z_k to determine where to evualuate f but there is also the measurement noise so it should not be)

Comment: @DidierPiau: $Z_n$ is independent on $\{X_k;k\leq n\}$ so $M_n$ is not $G_n$-measurable if $G_n\subseteq \sigma(X_0)\cup \sigma(Z_k;k\leq n-1)$ due to the fact that $Y_n = U_n - V_n$ and $U_n$ depends on $Z_n$.

Comment: See edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: @Didier.. I think I was not aware of how important the exact dependence of $X_k$ on it's predecessor is, and now when I try to apply your answer I see that I have to pay attention to the noisy-evaluation-thing as well :( and it becomes more like X_{k+1}= h(X_k, Z_k) + r_k/Z_k, where E(r_k| X_1, ..., X_k, Z_k)=0, or I could also say E(X_{k+1} ) = E(h(X_k, Z_k) ) and r_k independent (but without distribution information). I am sorry that I didn't see this from the beginning.. And how do we continue now? This question has become so confusing.. Can you open a chat maybe?

Comment: Indeed the exact dependence structure IS important. But in the situation you describe, it seems one can simply use the whole package $(r_k,Z_k)$ as $Z_k$ in my answer, modify the function $h$ accordingly, and apply my answer. As long as $X_{n+1}$ is a given function of $X_n$ and of plenty of other stuff and as long as this other stuff is independent of the whole past, you are done. Call me optimistic if you like but, where you see a confusing question, I see a solved one.

Answer (score 1):

Some information about the processes $X,Z$ will be extremely useful. E.g. if $X,Z$ are iid and mutually independent then $Y$ is iid process with the zero mean, hence $M$ is a martingale random walk.

*Edited:*
After a discussion with OP in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1402/baraddur) we clarified that $Y_k = S_k - \mathsf E[S_k|\mathcal F_k]$ for the filtration $\mathcal F_k = \mathcal F^X_k$. This result simply implies the martingale property of $(M,\mathcal F)$.

Comment: I don't have direct conditions on $X$. $X_{k+1}=X_k+f(X_k, Z_k)$. X_k and Z_k are independent and Z_k is iid.

Answer (score 0):

Also this is not a full answer, but just a try to expand Gotaurs comments, it would be too long for a comment.

I take $E_x(g(X))$ as conditional expectation $E(g(X)|x)$, did you mean this?
And after your comment I have to show that $Pg(x)=g(x)$ for all x

Now if I assume that $S_k$ is Markov then use $g(S_k)=S_k -E(S_k|X_k)$
$$ E_{s_k} [ g(S_k)] = g(s_k) \quad \forall s_k$$
$$ E[S_k - E(S_k|X_k) | S_k=s_k] = s_k - E(s_k)$$
which is always true and I guess something of what I wrote doesn't make any sense at all